# Change /javax.faces.resource prefix of resource URLs

Tags: jsf-2

When I use

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css">
```

or

```
<h:graphicImage library="images" name="image.jpg">
```

then in html I get something like this

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/appName/javax.faces.resource/styles.css.xhtml?ln=css" />
```

so the user can see which framework was used to write this app. How can I avoid showing `javax.faces.resource/styles.css.xhtml?ln=css` to the user, but also still using facelets(not html, like `<link rel=...`>)? It will be good when the user simply will see the path to the css file as `resources/css/styles.css`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not directly possible without reimplementing the entire [`ResourceHandler`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html) with help of a [`ResourceHandlerWrapper`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandlerWrapper.html) as [answered by lu4242 on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354464/change-javax-faces-resource-prefix-of-resource-urls/7372108#7372108), which is not exactly a trivial job. It's a hardcoded `public static final` field constant in [`ResourceHandler`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html) class, the [`ResourceHandler#RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html#RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER). You may want to post a feature request to make this externally configureable like as has happened for the [`NamingContainer`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) separator character during the JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0 step.

But why would you do this? There are a lot of other things which gives enough hints about the framework used. In case of JSF that can be the request URL pattern (`/faces/*`, `*.jsf` or `*.xhtml`), the response headers (`X-Powered-By`), specific hidden form fields (`javax.faces.ViewState`), the autogenerated client IDs (by default woodstocked), the JS libraries used (`jsf.js`), etcetera.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have never seen any framework specific fetures in most webapps, just plain html with javascript, so I thought that jsf provide such an opprtunity. Or maybe, I have never seen any JSF webapp on the web.

Comment: This answer is not true!!!!! the constant is used for the default ResourceHandler, but that does not means you can't use a default ResourceHandlerWrapper over the default one an write a full implementation that uses other different prefix structure. I'll write an answer for this one.

Comment: @lu4242: Ah right, that can also, didn't thought of it. But was it really needed to throw with those exclamation marks? Did you feel attacked or something? Sorry, that wasn't my intent.

Comment: No, no, don't get me wrong ;-) It is just the spec was designed to precisely allow extensible ResourceHandler implementations, like the question is asking.

Answer (score 5):

This is possible. The code on FacesServlet looks like this:

```
    ResourceHandler resourceHandler = facesContext.getApplication().getResourceHandler();

    // Call ResourceHandler.isResourceRequest(javax.faces.context.FacesContext).
    if (resourceHandler.isResourceRequest(facesContext))
    {
        // If this returns true call ResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(javax.faces.context.FacesContext).
        resourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(facesContext);
    }
```

The default implementation uses ResourceHandler#RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER constant by default, but it is technically possible to write a ResourceHandlerWrapper that uses other structure. The only problem is the wrapper should implement everything, and you can't delegate anything to the default algorithm. You can reuse the code on [MyFaces Shared](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/myfaces/shared/trunk_4.0.x/core/src/main/java/org/apache/myfaces/shared/resource/) but remember this are internals, so use something like maven shade plugin or a hard copy to relocate the package name.

What is not possible is change it for existing ResourceHandler implementations (for example, components that use a custom ResourceHandler implementation like t:captcha or other variants), because all those are tied to the constant.

Anyway, I created [MFCOMMONS-36](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MFCOMMONS-36) to add this to the extended ResourceHandler implementation that is being added on MyFaces Commons.

Comment: After all, everything is possible :) Nice one.