# Apache in front of JSF

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, jboss, mod-proxy

In Jboss AS 7:

Putting Apache in front of Jboss with this works fine:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080
```

So app is accessed by *domain.com/app*.

Problem appears when aiming for a clearer URL(Just *domain.com*):

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/app
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/app
```

All **javax.faces.resource** are not delivered in the second case, because they don't use the *war* context URL.

Any idea how to get the faces resources in the second case? Maybe just move to mod_jk?

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7356094/1341526) about ResourceHandler, helps pretty much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSF [`ResourceHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html) emits URLs with the `<contextPath>/javax.faces.resource/` route, albeit indirectly through the ScriptRenderer, StyleSheetRenderer etc.

Since you're omitting the app name (context Path) in the ProxyPass directive, you'll need to use a URL rewriter to omit the URLs before they're served to the browser. Refer the answers in [the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905946/jsf-url-rewriting-solution-needed) on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

I use multiple `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` entries to accommodate for the different context paths JSF might spit out. The following is typically my default for every domain (`ServerName`)...

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    ServerAdmin email@email.com
    DocumentRoot "/"
    ServerName "dev.mydomain.com"

    ProxyPass /MyApp/ ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/MyApp/
    ProxyPassReverse /MyApp/ http://127.0.0.1:80/MyApp/

    ProxyPass /MyApp ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/MyApp/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:80

    ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/MyApp/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:80/     
</VirtualHost>
```

The above configuration will allow access to the web app using any of the following URIs:

```
http://dev.myapp.com/MyApp/
http://dev.myapp.com/MyApp
http://dev.myapp.com/
```

Therefore, `http://dev.myapp.com/javax.faces.resource/example.css` would hit the last rule and be routed to `http://dev.myapp.com/MyApp/javax.faces.resource/example.css`. Additionally, `http://dev.myapp.com/MyApp/javax.faces.resource/example.css` would hit the first rule and pass through as is.

**NOTES:**

1. **The order is important!** These rules will be processed top down. If you put the `ProxyPass` for '/' first then the other conditions would never get processed. Since every URI has a `/` after the host name, every request would be processed with that condition... which is why the `/` condition should always go last.
2. I highly recommend using the Apache JServ Protocol (`ajp`) Connector (instead of HTTP). It's built into Apache and JBOSS, it's easy to turn on and it significantly improves performance... especially if there's any kind of binary data (images) being routed. https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/config/ajp.html

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem and didn't found a way to configure an apache server either.

If you just want to tidy up your URL I can recommend [URLRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) this helped me in that case.

Hope this helpes, have Fun!