# Remap javax.faces.resources to a different path

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, ajp

I have a jsf/primefaces app. It has both internal and external facing side grouped into two different directories such as xhtml/internal and xhtml/external. Access to the internal site is controlled by a filter based on your IP. If your IP is on the internal range, you can get access to xhtml/internal but you still have to login.

The access to the application is controlled by IS through the ajp protocol so I have to map either the top level url such as mysite or mysite/xhtml/external. I have gone with mapping mysite since the IP range check was enough for my security needs. At the last moment, my supervisor decided that IP security is not good enough.

I would like to map the site as mysite/xhtml/external using AJP but jsf has his own resource handling. So even if I somehow create a clone of the javascript/css files, I cannot serve them from xhtml/external url. Here's what the jsf/primefaces does to a resource request

mysite/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-bootstrap

Is it possible to map that so instead of javax.faces.resource, it should be  xhtml/external/javax.faces.resource ? Thanks

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  The typical way to handle jsf resources is to add a custom rule to your filter so that it is exempt from requiring a login.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be impossible. This is due to the fact javax.faces.resources is a static final string [ResourceHandler#RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html#RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER).

Unfortunately this cannot be overridden even with reflection. Read more about it [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354464/change-javax-faces-resource-prefix-of-resource-urls?lq=1)